# Legally bypassing Facebook Graph API limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

We are developing a project where we need to send probably hundreds of requests to Facebook's graph API per minute. Our main requirement is to continuously monitor hundreds of comments (and possibly posts) of our own page, and respond back where required. Though we haven't tested our complete project on live system yet. But we are sure that it is going to exceed the API's rate limit. We were wondering whether facebook provide some premium access to API where this limit can be bypassed? We have looked into their documentation but are unable to find anything. Or is there any way where we can monitor our page continuously without worrying about this rate limit.

Thank you

Comment: No, there is no "premium access". You should look into Webhooks, so that Facebook informs your app when something changes in the relevant fields of the page.

Comment: You can check the doc on rate limiting and how to best handle it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting/
Alternatively, as @CBroe suggested, consider using Wehbooks: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/